# How do I use Static Objects in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, static

I am implemeneting a Log4Net toolkit

TO use:

```
  private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);



public string MyFunc()
{
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log.Debug("function called on: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

I always need to call the:

```
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In ASP.NET application i can call this in Session_Start event only once but what to do this in a WCF Service application

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It will depend on where you are hosting your service.If you hosted in iis then you can use context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) by extending HttpApplication and use it in global.asax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) and [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) for your service. Typically, a WCF service is stateless (using the InstanceContextMode PerCall). This results in a new service object being created for every call, so you'd have to setup your logging for every call (for example in the constructor)